# Problemas al instalar pluguin SQLite-net_pcl Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor eh estado preguntado a algunos colegas y no tengo ninguna respuesta hasta el momento.